# How do you convert codes (as in encoding, Encoding) to encoded character strings?

Tags: r, pdf, fonts, character-encoding, character

How do you specify individual characters by code, and produce a character vector?

In Python 3, you can do something like

```
''.join(map(chr, range(255)))
```

The immediate application is to make a character code chart using `pdf` and the Base 14 fonts for later reference.

I am looking for something like

```
foo <- function(x, y) {
    # WHAT GOES HERE?
}

bar <- foo(0:255, "PDF")
```

Then

```
pdf(file="~/test.pdf", what else?)
plot(0)
text(0, 0, labels=bar)
```

should label (0, 0) with *whatever* characters correspond with `bar`.

Comment: You can get individual letters, you can use `letters` for lower case or `LETTERS` for upper case. To convert a selection into a string, you can use `paste(letters[c(1:5, 9, 10, 2)], collapse = '')`, you can ignore the `paste` and get individual alphabets as vectors?

Comment: OK, but what about arbitraty characters that can be specified by number (and perhaps can't be specified any other way).

Answer (score 1):

The `as.raw()` function converts numbers to raw character codes.  The `rawToChar()` function converts those to characters.  A complication is that most systems other than Windows use UTF-8 encodings nowadays, and those are multi-byte encodings, but not all values correspond to legal characters.

You'll get an error if you try

```
rawToChar(as.raw(0:255))
```

because 0 is not a legal byte in a string.  If you try

```
rawToChar(as.raw(1:255))
```

you'll get a string that prints like this in my console:

```
[1] "\001\002\003\004\005\006\a\b\t\n\v\f\r\016\017\020\021\022\023\024\025\026\027\030\031\032\033\034\035\036\037 !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\177\x80\x81\x82\x83\x84\x85\x86\x87\x88\x89\x8a\x8b\x8c\x8d\x8e\x8f\x90\x91\x92\x93\x94\x95\x96\x97\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9c\x9d\x9e\x9f\xa0\xa1\xa2\xa3\xa4\xa5\xa6\xa7\xa8\xa9\xaa\xab\xac\xad\xae\xaf\xb0\xb1\xb2\xb3\xb4\xb5\xb6\xb7\xb8\xb9\xba\xbb\xbc\xbd\xbe\xbf\xc0\xc1\xc2\xc3\xc4\xc5\xc6\xc7\xc8\xc9\xca\xcb\xcc\xcd\xce\xcf\xd0\xd1\xd2\xd3\xd4\xd5\xd6\xd7\xd8\xd9\xda\xdb\xdc\xdd\xde\xdf\xe0\xe1\xe2\xe3\xe4\xe5\xe6\xe7\xe8\xe9\xea\xeb\xec\xed\xee\xef\xf0\xf1\xf2\xf3\xf4\xf5\xf6\xf7\xf8\xf9\xfa\xfb\xfc\xfd\xfe\xff"
```

If you use `multiple = TRUE` in the `rawToChar` call, you'll get a separate string from each byte; in that case, you can include 0 for an empty string.  This will plot the table:

```
nibble1 <- rep(0:15, each=16)
nibble2 <- rep(0:15, 16)
byte <- nibble1*16 + nibble2
pdf("table.pdf")
plot(nibble1, nibble2, type = "n") 
text(nibble1, nibble2, rawToChar(as.raw(0:255), multiple = TRUE))
dev.off()
```

However, this is not the Adobe Standard Encoding, it is whatever encoding is used on your system.  If you really want to see the Adobe encoding, you need to convert to Unicode before displaying.  This is tricky, because `iconv()` (at least on my system) doesn't know the Adobe encoding.  However, this sort of does it:

```
ASE2Unicode <- read.delim("ftp://ftp.unicode.org/Public/MAPPINGS/VENDORS/ADOBE/stdenc.txt", 
                          comment.char="#", head=FALSE)
ASE2Unicode$V1 <- strtoi(ASE2Unicode$V1, 16)
ASE2Unicode$V2 <- strtoi(ASE2Unicode$V2, 16)
chars <- rep("", 256)
chars[ASE2Unicode$V2] <- intToUtf8(ASE2Unicode$V1, multiple = TRUE)
pdf("table2.pdf")
plot(nibble1, nibble2, type = "n") 
text(nibble1, nibble2, chars)
dev.off()
```

It's only "sort of" because some characters don't survive the translation:

[image]

Comment: Are you saying that the `pdf` function expects text encoded as UTF-8, and that it knows how to map that to characters in a (in this case) base 14 character set?

Comment: No, the `pdf` function doesn't directly deal with text at all.  In the example, it's the `text` function that deals with text, and it expects one of the supported encodings within R, i.e. the native encoding, Latin-1, or UTF-8.  Often the native encoding is Latin-1 or UTF-8, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I meant ".... the `pdf` _device_ that is returned by the `pdf` function expects text...." And you are saying that the `text` function "knows" what the `pdf` _device_ expects, and delivers the appropriate informatuon, right?

Comment: I was talking about the text that the user inputs.  The user deals with the `text()` function, and has to deliver text in the appropriate format for that function.  The way that R functions interact with the graphics driver is documented in the R Internals Manual, section 6.1.3 "Handling text".